# Postgres 11 logical replication partition table

Tags: postgresql, logical-replication

Getting an error on Postgres 11 when creating a publication for a partitioned table. ERROR: table is a partitioned table Detail : Adding partitioned tables to publications is not supported. Hint: You can add the table partitions individually. Is there a workaround for this.

Comment: "*Is there a workaround for this*" - no. You could wait for Postgres 13 where this is possible.

Comment: Which should be released tomorrow, so not much wait.